# Import Email Id's In Magento Newsletter

Tags: magento

I need to import 50k email ids for magento newsletter subscription.I found a tutorial to import, http://www.g31zone.com/?p=187. Is importing 50k email ids through an array is feasible?Is their any other way to import?

**Edit**

Is it possible to import customer name through this array?

Looking forward for your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Jan+Wohlfeil/extension/2358/newsletter-address-import/reviews

Newsletters are in a different table to customers and import quickly.

With 50K subscribers you may want a proper newsletter manager, e.g. one where you can track bounces etc. CiviCRM CiviMail or phpnewsletter should do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Import Multiple Email Subscribers using .CSV**

Create a .CSV file and title two columns `subscriber_email` and `subscriber_status`. Ensure these are correct else the import will not work.

Under `subscriber_email` list all email addresses. Under `subscriber_status` make sure each field value is `1`.

In phpMyAdmin under `Newsletter_Subscriber` click import. Using the browse function select you .CSV file, ensure it's set to UTF-8 andfile format is .CSV.

Under "format specific options" in the column names filed enter: `subscriber_email,subscriber_status`.

Click go and all you fields will be imported instantly.

Finally, login to the Magento Control Panel and under Newsletter Subscribers you'll be able to view all the imported email subscribers.

http://www.littlekidsbeds.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

You can add records directly to newsletter_subscriber table, choose correct store_id, customer_id = 0, subscriber_status = 1, subscriber_confirm_code empty.

Alternatively you could create simple PHP script that would use newsletter subscriber model, an example:

```
 <?php
    require_once "/path/to/Mage.php";

    Mage::app();

    $subscribers = array('email1@server1.com', 'email2@server2.com', ...);

    foreach ($subscribers as $email) {
      Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
    }
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion if you just need to import the emails and nothing else (e.g. no customer account association). You can just import the CSV directly into the `newsletter_subscriber` table and then mass-update the `store_id` and `subscriber_status` directly via SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah go ahead had reset password of 30K customers in the same manner not to long ago :)

Comment: It is useful to have a comment for why this has been downvoted. In my view it doesn't give a wrong answer.